How does this DAX query work, I want to understand the flow of this query
When SUMX should have 1st argument as a table then why did we use DISTINCT  it will return a column of distinct product categories and also why do we use CALCULATE and Sum as second argument.
TotalSalesByUniqueCategory = SUMX(
DISTINCT(DimProduct[Category]),
CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit]) )
)



DISTINCT(DimProduct[Category]):

This is the first argument of the SUMX function, and it returns a table containing distinct values of the column DimProduct[Category].
Even though it looks like it returns a column, in DAX, a column is considered a single-column table, so it is a valid input for SUMX.

Example:
If your DimProduct[Category] contains:
Category
---------
A
B
A
C
B

Then DISTINCT(DimProduct[Category]) would return:
Category
---------
A
B
C




SUMX():

SUMX is an iterator function. It iterates over each row of the table provided as the first argument (DISTINCT(DimProduct[Category])).
For each row in this distinct list of categories, it evaluates the expression provided as the second argument.


CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])):

The second argument of SUMX is CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])).
CALCULATE modifies the context in which the SUM(FactSales[Profit]) is evaluated.
When iterating through each category (from the distinct list), CALCULATE changes the filter context to consider only the current category in the iteration.
SUM(FactSales[Profit]) then computes the total profit only for the current category in the iteration.


Summary:

SUMX iterates over each unique product category (A, B, C).
For each category, it evaluates CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])), which sums up the FactSales[Profit] for that specific category.
Finally, SUMX adds up all these individual sums to produce the total profit across all distinct categories.



Example:
Let's consider a small dataset:
DimProduct Table:
    | Category |
    |----------|
    | A        |
    | B        |
    | A        |
    | C        |
    | B        |

FactSales Table:
    | Product | Category | Profit |
    |---------|----------|--------|
    | P1      | A        | 100    |
    | P2      | B        | 200    |
    | P3      | A        | 150    |
    | P4      | C        | 300    |
    | P5      | B        | 250    |

Step-by-Step Execution:

DISTINCT(DimProduct[Category]) returns: A, B, C.
For each category:

For A: CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])) returns 100 + 150 = 250.
For B: CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])) returns 200 + 250 = 450.
For C: CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[Profit])) returns 300.


SUMX then sums these values: 250 + 450 + 300 = 1000.

Why Use CALCULATE?

CALCULATE is necessary here because it modifies the filter context for each category in the iteration. Without CALCULATE, the SUM(FactSales[Profit]) would consider the entire dataset instead of being filtered by the current category.

Why Use SUMX Instead of SUM?

SUM operates directly on a column and sums its values. In this case, we want to iterate over a list of distinct categories, and for each category, calculate the total profit. This is why SUMX, an iterator function, is used.

Summary
The formula:

Iterates over each distinct category (A, B, C).
Uses CALCULATE to filter the sales data by the current category.
Sums the profits for each category and aggregates these totals.


"Thank you, Michal, for your response! The CALCULATE function changes its context based on subcategories. It starts by taking the first subcategory and filters the data accordingly for that specific subcategory."
